# Programmatically launch other app in Split View

Tags: ios, ipad, splitview

I have an app that opens another app with a Custom URL scheme in iPad. I want to be able to open this other app in Split View along with the active app programatically, so the user does not have to manually open the other app and then put them in Split View.

I have checked but I cannot find any documentation about it (so it might not be possible to do so).

Comment: Not possible. You can only request a new scene of your own app.

Comment: alright, that's what I was afraid of... thank you